# Create a subdomain automatically

Tags: php

I'm not asking for code, but for some tips. I want to create a system, that automatically create a subdomain, for example, after the payment be approved by PayPal, I create a subdomain, such as: stackoverflow.mywebsite.com

```
<?php
  // Ignore this code. 
  $createSubDomain = 'stackoverflow.mywebsite.com';
  $createSubDomain = 'stackoverflow.mywebsite.com';
  $createSubDomain = 'stackoverflow.mywebsite.com';
  if($craeteSubDomain !== '') { echo "created"; }
?>
```

Just that. I guess that I can handle with the content after subdomain creation. :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.9lessons.info/2016/03/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomains-using-php-and-htaccess.html) is a pretty good guide. 
Basically you are going to want to register the `*` subdomain to point to your server. Then you need to configure your .htaccess file to handle it.

Your .htaccess file should look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourwebsite\.com $
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourwebsite_folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /yourwebsite_folder/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.yourwebsite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourwebsite_folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /yourwebsite_folder/$1
```

If you want to learn more about .htaccess you can look [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

In your php file instead of creating a subdomain you are creating a folder. when people try to load newsub.example.com the .htaccess file points them to example.com/yourwebsite_folder/newsub

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMK! I'll read this guide and, thanks for the explantion too  . ^-^